# Installation of Ruby script - initialize error

Tags: ruby, linux

I have a problem with the basics of installing a Ruby script on my Ubuntu 15.04 linux box.

The repository of the script can be found in [Github](https://github.com/vdaubry/youtube-multiple-dl). The installation guide is not very detailed at all.

I have Ruby 2.2.3p173 and gem v2.4.5.1. I cloned the repo and did a `bundle install` but I get errors when executing the script.

How can I get this script properly installed and be able to run it from anywhere?

Errors:

```
 root@box15990:/usr/local/bin/youtube-multiple-dl/bin# ruby youtube-multiple-dl -h
/usr/local/bin/youtube-multiple-dl/db/database.rb:32:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/database.yml(Errno::ENOENT)
        from /usr/local/bin/youtube-multiple-dl/db/database.rb:32:in `open'
        from /usr/local/bin/youtube-multiple-dl/db/database.rb:32:in `config'
        from /usr/local/bin/youtube-multiple-dl/db/database.rb:26:in `connect'
        from youtube-multiple-dl:5:in `<main>'
```

Comment: 1) Don't run it from the `bin` directory.

Comment: @DaveNewton, followed your advice and got the following error: `ruby: No such file or directory -- youtube-multiple-dl (LoadError)`

Comment: `ruby youtube-multiple-dl -h` doesn't sound like the right command to use. If your path is correct and it installed correctly you should be able to use `youtube-multiple-dl -h`.

Comment: @theTinMan, You are right and I am currently facing issues with setting the path. I am running this on ubuntu 15.04. I have set another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656669/setting-path-variables-and-running-ruby-script) to avoid diverting from the main topic here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Questions about managing the system really belong on [su]. Stack Overflow is more for code problems, and spreads into code-related problems. Your question is more about how to set up your environment and correctly install software, not use or program the particular program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run the DB migration task:

   ```
   $ rake db:migrate
   ```
2. Don't run it from the bin directory, instead at the project root:

   ```
   $ bin/youtube-multiple-dl
   ```

Example output:

```
➜  youtube-multiple-dl git:(master) bin/youtube-multiple-dl -l
ID   | URL                                                                                   | STATUS       | INFOS                                        |
```

(I have nothing in the queue.)

```
➜  youtube-multiple-dl git:(master) bin/youtube-multiple-dl -s
[Worker(host:TD1000557.local pid:20020)] Starting job worker
I, [2015-11-11T12:04:25.859733 #20020]  INFO -- : 2015-11-11T12:04:25-0500: [Worker(host:TD1000557.local pid:20020)] Starting job worker
```

Then you can add videos to download from a new term window in the same directory:

```
➜  youtube-multiple-dl git:(master) bin/youtube-multiple-dl -a https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=FRcb3CC7ayU
```

The terminal you started it in will show something like:

```
waiting for download to start...
[Worker(host:TD1000557.local pid:20080)] Job YoutubeMultipleDL::Download#call_downloader_without_delay (id=1) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with RuntimeError: download failed
E, [2015-11-11T12:05:55.796843 #20080] ERROR -- : 2015-11-11T12:05:55-0500: [Worker(host:TD1000557.local pid:20080)] Job YoutubeMultipleDL::Download#call_downloader_without_delay (id=1) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with RuntimeError: download failed
```

Don't know why it doesn't work, both `youtube-dl` and `youtube-multiple-dl` are new to me.

Comment: Ahh Thanks Dave! How would i call the script if I am not inside the project root?

Comment: @MaryCoding Don't know; you could the `bin` directory to your path.