# Setting path variables and running Ruby script

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This is my first time working with a Ruby script, and, in order to run this script, I have to first `cd` into the root of the project, which is `/usr/local/bin/youtube-multiple-dl` and then execute the script as `bin/youtube-multiple-dl`.

I tried setting the PATH variable

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/youtube-multiple-dl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

in hopes that I can run this from anywhere on the machine without having to `cd` to the project's root, however, no luck with that so far.

System: Ubuntu 15.04 server

[Script Repo](https://github.com/vdaubry/youtube-multiple-dl)

My current way of executing the script is:

```
root@box15990:~# cd /usr/local/bin/youtube-multiple-dl
root@box15990:/usr/local/bin/youtube-multiple-dl# bin/youtube-multiple-dl
```

Desired way of executing script:

```
root@box15990:~# youtube-multiple-dl
```

How can I properly set the enviroment path for this script in order to run from anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/youtube-multiple-dl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

isn't how we set a PATH entry.

The PATH is a list of *directories* to be searched, not a list of files.

Typically, the PATH should contain something like:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

somewhere in it.

If it doesn't, then you want to modify it using a text editor, such as `nano`, `pico` or `vim` using *one* of these commands:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
pico ~/.bash_profile
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

You probably want one of the first two over `vim` as vim, while being extremely powerful and one of the most-used editors in the world, is also not overly intuitive if you're not used to it. You can use `man nano` or `man pico` to learn about the other too.

Once your in your file editor, scroll to the bottom and remove the line you added. Then find the `/usr/bin` section in your PATH and add `/usr/local/bin:` before it. `:` is the delimiter between directories. That change will tell the shell to look in `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, so that any things you added to the `/usr/local/bin` directory will be found before the system-installed code, which is in `/usr/bin`.

It's possible that there isn't a PATH statement in the file. If you don't see one, simply add:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

After modifying your ~/.bash_profile, save the file and exit the editor, and then  restart your shell. You can do that by exiting and re-opening a terminal window, or by running:

```
 exec $SHELL
```

at the command-line.

At that point, running:

```
echo $PATH
```

should reflect the change to your path.

To confirm that the change is in effect, you can run:

```
which youtube-multiple.dl
```

and you should get back:

```
/usr/local/bin/youtube-multiple.dl
```

At that point you should be able to run:

```
youtube-multiple.dl -h
```

and get back a response showing the built-in help. This is because the shell will search the path, starting with the first defined directory, and continue until it exhausts the list, and will execute the first file matching that name.

Because of the difficulties you're having, I'd strongly recommend reading some tutorials about managing a *nix system. It's not overly hard to learn the basics, and having an understanding of how the shell finds files and executes them is essential for anyone programming a scripting language like Ruby, Python, Perl, etc. We're using the OS constantly, installing files for system and user's use, and doing so correctly and safely is very important for the security and stability of the machine.